# In Scala, is there a way to map over a collection while passing a value along fold-style?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In Scala, is there a way to map over a collection while passing a value along fold-style? Something like:

```
case class TxRecord(name: String, amount: Int)
case class TxSummary(name: String, amount: Int, balance: Int)

val txRecords: Seq[TxRecord] = txRecordService.getSortedTxRecordsOfUser("userId")

val txSummarys: Seq[TxSummary] = txRecords.foldMap(0)((sum, txRecord) =>
  (sum + txRecord.amount, TxSummary(txRecord.name, txRecord.amount, sum + txRecord.amount)))
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: is that what you trying to get



     val txSummarys: Seq[TxSummary] = txRecords.foldLeft((0, Seq.empty[TxSummary])) { case ((sum, summaries), txRecord) =>
    val balance = sum + txRecord.amount
    balance -> (summaries :+ TxSummary(txRecord.name, txRecord.amount, balance))
  }._2 
?
or you want to reduce all records to one summary?